# Decomposition of Determinant of Sub-Matrices of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-decomposition

Consider an $n \times n$ matrix $\bf A$ over a field. Let $\bf A$ is constructed by the product of $n \times n$ matrices $B_i$, for $1\leq i \leq m$ which means 
$$
{\bf A}=\prod_{i=1}^m\, {\bf B}_i\, .
$$
From Linear Algebra we know that the relation between determinant of $\bf A$ and $\bf B_i$'s are as follows:
$$
{\det(\bf A)}=\prod_{i=1}^m\, {\det(\bf B}_i)\, .
$$
Suppose that an $k \times k$ sub-matrix of $\bf A$ for $1\leq k \leq n$  is denoted with ${\bf A}^{(k)}$.

**My question:**

Is there a condition that can be used to check  ${\bf A}^{(k)}$ is singular or non-singular matrix based on the determinants of $\bf B_i$'s or sub-matrices of $\bf B_i$'s.

Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Comment: Every entry of $B_i$ is a submatrix of $B_i$.

Comment: @user1551 I can not understand what did you mean by your comment. Is it possible to ask you to explain more. Thanks

Comment: I mean your question is vague. $\det A^{(k)}$ is a polynomial in the entries of $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_m$. Since every entry of $B_i$ is a submatrix of $B_i$, the answer to your question is undoubtedly yes, because "$\det A^{(k)}=0$" is already such a condition.

Comment: @user1551 Maybe the first comment of [this question in mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306077/decomposition-of-determinant-of-sub-matrices-of-a-matrix) be helpful to make clean my question.

Comment: You seem to be asking the same question as you have just referenced, and the first comment there gives you an answer. (I am pretty sure it's  *the* answer in general.)

Comment: @ancientmathematician Although the first comment of that post, mentioned a nice relation betwen determinant of $\bf A$ and $\bf B_i$'s, checking singularity of $\bf A$ by the given relation is too difficult. Do you have any idea about checking  singularity of $\bf A$ by the given relation.

Comment: In general no, but even in the case $k=1$ and $m=2$ I'd have to multiply it out to decide. If you know a better way in that case then Gauss Bonnet tells you how to do the general case.